# Adding 'tick marks' to histogram python (JES)

Tags: python, python-3.x, histogram, jes

Hi guys sorry if bad question but I have this histogram (pic attached) I need to somehow in my code include 'tick marks' up the horizontal axis as well as numbers 0,2,4,,6,8,10, 10 being the maximum in my example.

I have no idea how to add these tick marks I cannot use imports, dicts, anything like that. The closest idea that I have is some loop including

```
i * ([(max-min)/5])
```

where max and min are the beginning and end of the horizontal axis.

Have been staring at this for over a week and this is the final piece and I am drawing a blank so any help would be very appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To customise the appearance of the ticks, you can use the **Axes.tick_params()** method.

ex:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(datasetname['Bronze'],women_degrees['Craft'],label='datasetname')
ax.tick_params(bottom="on", top="off", left="on", right="off")
plt.show()
```